# how i can redirect to the same page from user click login button by facebook

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-login

How can I redirect to the same page from user click login button by facebook, my code is working fine on home page, if user click from diff page then there is a problem, it is redirecting to homepage, not that page.
How to resolve it?

```
// javascript sdk
<?php
    if(!$fbuser){
        $fbuser = null;
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
        echo '<a href='.$loginUrl.' class="btn btn-default facebook"> <i class="fa fa-facebook modal-icons"></i> Sign In with Facebook </a>';   
    }else{
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
        $user = new FB_users();
        $user_data = $user->checkUser('facebook',$user_profile['id'],$user_profile['first_name'],$user_profile['last_name'],$user_profile['email'],$user_profile['gender'],$user_profile['locale'],$user_profile['picture']['data']['url']);
        // Add email in session & reload page

        // i have used javascript sdk in my page.
        $_SESSION['email'] = $user_profile['email']; 
        echo '<script>parent.window.location.reload(true);</script>'; 
    }
                                        ?>
    =====that my code on login page=========
    so how to do it .
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    if(!$fbuser) {
        $fbuser = null;
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
        echo '<a href='.$loginUrl.' class="btn btn-default facebook"> <i class="fa fa-facebook modal-icons"></i> Sign In with Facebook </a>';   
    } else {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
        $user = new FB_users();
        $user_data = $user->checkUser('facebook',$user_profile['id'],$user_profile['first_name'],$user_profile['last_name'],$user_profile['email'],$user_profile['gender'],$user_profile['locale'],$user_profile['picture']['data']['url']);
        // Add email in session & reload page

        // i have used javascript sdk in my page.
        $_SESSION['email'] = $user_profile['email']; 

        // do not place HTML before this line
        // filter $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] for your security
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: how to add $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); in other page when user click from that page ..

Comment: You can store the HTTP_REFERER in a SESSION on every page load. After you have stored the HTTP_REFERER, you can call it in your script.

Comment: but in this line i am defining     i am defing redirect_uri, how to chnage it                                                            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));

Comment: set $homeurl to $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ... but I am not sure, if you have to enter it in your facebook app. I have found two keys called 'next' and 'cancel'. `$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('next'=>$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'cancel': 'http://.../cancel.php', 'scope'=>$fbPermissions));`

Comment: that is redirecting perfectly but the value is not coming in session, i.e it is not showing logout.

Comment: I think that you have to redirect to your posted script and then redirect your user to the referer page. The best way to do that, is to store the referer in a SESSION before you go to facebook. Something like that `<?php

 $_SESSION['LAST_VISITED'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

 $last_visited = isset($_SESSION['LAST_VISITED']) ? $_SESSION['LAST_VISITED'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 unset($_SESSION['LAST_VISITED']);

 ?>`. You have to do that, because the new REFERER is facebook and you need the old one.

Comment: this code is also not working i have tried it. it is redirecting but not taking the session value,can u show your dummy code , then i will change acc  to that ..

Comment: Have you forgotten to write `session_start();` at the beginning of your script?